# .NET Core ASHX 404

Tags: asp.net-core

I've got a file in my wwwroot folder called myfile.ashx, but when I browse to https://www.example.com/myfile.ashx I'm getting a 404 error.

My first thought was this is a MIME Type issue.  So I tried adding this to my web.config, but that didn't help.

```
<staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".ashx" mimeType="text/html" />
</staticContent>
```

I am hoping someone here might be able to point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question here.  For .NET Core I need to make my *.ashx handler a Middleware.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/http-modules?view=aspnetcore-6.0#migrating-handler-code-to-middleware